What is the difference between MPI broadcast, and just passing the broadcast data as input?
I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of how the comm.bcast method works in mpi4py.  From what I understand it broadcasts the data to all of the processes.
However, upon accidental experimentation I discovered that if I pass the data as input into the method it still does the broadcasting, and doesn't change.
For example, the code below will execute as expected, regardless of whether I call comm.bcast or not:

input_data = [['a','f','d'], ['b','c', 'd']] 
def process_chunk(include_list, chunk): 
    print('i am processing chunk ', chunk) 
    return [x for x in chunk if x in include_list] 

def process_data(input_data): 
    from mpi4py import MPI 
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 
    size = comm.Get_size() 
    rank = comm.Get_rank() 

    data = None 
    if rank == 0: 
        data = input_data 
        print('we will be scattering:', data)   

    include_list = ['a','d','f'] 
    ### if I comment out the next line, nothing changes 
    #include_list = comm.bcast(include_list, root=0) 
    data = comm.scatter(data, root=0) 
    data = process_chunk(include_list, data) 
    newData = comm.gather(data, root=0)   

    if rank == 0: 
        print('master:',newData)   
    return   

process_data(input_data) 

I run the above code using command mpirun -n 2 python3 process_chunk.py (where process_chunk.py is a file with the above code), and I get the following output:
we will be scattering: [['a', 'f', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'd']]
i am processing chunk  ['a', 'f', 'd']
i am processing chunk  ['b', 'c', 'd']
master: [['a', 'f', 'd'], ['d']]

My question is:  If I can just pass the necessary information (in this case include_list) as input to a particular method, and all ranks seem to receive it, then what is the use of comm.bcast?

If you are doing any operation on the root processors, like read operations, and you want to broadcast to all the processors, then it is handy. Now a days, with MPI-2 version, you can have parallel read and write operations, in such cases comm.bcast becomes obsolete. They got it new version for backward compatibility.
